# get columns from multiple tables from multiples entities in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, multiple-tables

I would like to create a datagrid which would contains 5 columns.

Each column from a different table and each table is from a different entity.

How should i do that in silverlight ?

I'm actually able to get the data from 1 table and display it in the datagrid but combining the entities seems complicated.

Thank you.

Comment: The short answer is use a ViewModel.  The long answer requires you to post the definitions of your entities and what the resulting table should look like.

Comment: Ok, do you have any link or info about how to use the ViewModel please ?

Answer (score 0):

Create Single  Store Procedure  And Take N Number of Columns  from  N number of Tables .